# Creating ZipArchive from grpc connection

Tags: c#, zip, grpc-c#

I have troubles with creating ZipArchive from grpc connection.
Schema: i have service with zip creating function. I got some data from third party service, generated csv file based on this data and put it into zip archive.
After that, i got memorystream (which is parent for zip), read it till the end, got strings, send it to another service and clean it. In my case this is necessary because there is huge possibility that data from third party services will be huge, so i need to save opportunity for chunk sending.
After closing zip with using, i send eocd bytes.

On the other side, i got those strings, convert them to byte arrays, union it and trying to recreate zip file.

ZipArchive successfully created, but there is no entries. I got an error `"Error executing Write request: Number of entries expected in End Of Central Directory does not correspond to number of entries in Central Directory."`
After exploring entrails of ZipArchive class, i found that central directory expected one file, but i got zero.

Number of bytes in both service (sender\receiver) is equal.
And there is 100% zip, because byte headers are corresponding with zip archive specs.
I have no idea what is wrong.
Code is below.

Service Sender

```
// just call for destination
    using var call = await _destinationService.InitCall();

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var zip = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
        {
            var entry = zip.CreateEntry($"{Model.FileName}.{Model.Format}");
            using var writer = new StreamWriter(entry.Open(), Model.Encoding);
            var csvConfiguration = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            {
                Delimiter = Model.Delimiter
            };
            using var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, csvConfiguration);

            var columns = await _exportService.GetAndWriteColumns(csv, firstChunk, Model, cancellationToken);
            // initalChunk to memoryStream
            await _exportService.PerformExport();

            while (_substreamData.TryDequeue(out var data) || !_isSubstreamEof)
            {
                // next chunks
                await _exportService.PerformExport();
            }
        }
        // sending eocd bytes after closing zip
        await _writeDataService.WriteDataPartAsync(call, stream, cancellationToken);
        await call.RequestStream.CompleteAsync();
    } 

    // PerformingExport 
    public async Task PerformExport(CsvWriter csv, StreamWriter writer)
    {
    // generating csv, getting data from third party services
    await csv.FlushAsync();
                await writer.FlushAsync();
    
                await WriteDataPartAsync(call, stream, cancellationToken);
                stream.Clear();
    }
    public async Task WriteDataPartAsync(
        AsyncDuplexStreamingCall<WriteData, WriteResponse> call,
        Stream stream,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, leaveOpen:true))
        {
            var streamString = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync(cancellationToken);

            await call.RequestStream.WriteAsync(
                new WriteData
                {
                    DataPart = new WriteChunk
                    {
                        Data = streamString
                    }
                },
                cancellationToken);
        }
    }
    
    public static void Clear(this MemoryStream source)
    {
        var buffer = source.GetBuffer();
        Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        source.Position = 0;
        source.SetLength(0);
    }
```

Service receiver

```
var bytes = new List<byte[]>();
while (await requestStream.MoveNext(context.CancellationToken))
{
    try
    {
        var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestStream.Current.DataPart.Data);
        bytes.Add(data);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"Error executing Write request: {ex.Message}");
        errors.Add(ex.Message);
    }
}

var stream1 = new MemoryStream(bytes.SelectMany(x => x).ToArray());
using var zipArchiveSubexport = new ZipArchive(stream1); // success
var t = zipArchiveSubexport.Entries.First(); // error because of number if entries
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Important addition: sender service successfully created zip archive from source memory stream.

Comment: as a general rule, try to debug a single thing at a time. Is the raw data transmitted correctly? Is the raw data correctly converted to a csv? Is data correctly added to the zip archive? Trying to use grpc, csv, and ziparchive together will make it much more difficult to locate the error. Better to try to separate each part, and write unit tests so you are reasonably confident each part works as expected.

Comment: You need to reposition the stream `stream.Position = 0` just before you call `WriteDataPartAsync`

Comment: @Charlieface there is reposition after writedatapart - stream.Cleare().
Added position=0 before call - no effect. still wrong number of entries

Comment: Why are you reading and writing it as a string? You may be getting weird Unicode changes. If you have bytes keep them as bytes, don't convert back and forwards.

Comment: i'm afraid there is no chance that i could change protobuf files. It has to be string =(

Comment: Then you'll have to Base64 the data otherwise it could be parsed incorrectly. You can't just arbitrarily create UTF8 out of random bits of zip files.

Comment: @Charlieface you were right. It's all about encoding. I rewrite it on base 64 and that damnable thing start working. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue here is that you are reading it as if it's encoded as a UTF8 string, which isn't going to work as many bytes are not compatible with UTF8.

You need to pass bytes directly

```
public async Task WriteDataPartAsync(
    AsyncDuplexStreamingCall<WriteData, WriteResponse> call,
    Stream stream,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await call.RequestStream.WriteAsync(
            new WriteData
            {
                DataPart = new WriteChunk
                {
                    Data = stream.ToArray(),
                }
            },
            cancellationToken);
}
```

And on the other side:

```cs
var stream1 = new MemoryStream(requestStream.Current.DataPart.Data);
using var zipArchiveSubexport = new ZipArchive(stream1);
var t = zipArchiveSubexport.Entries.First();
```

If you can't change the format of the packet, you will have to use Base64 encoding instead.

```
public async Task WriteDataPartAsync(
    AsyncDuplexStreamingCall<WriteData, WriteResponse> call,
    Stream stream,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await call.RequestStream.WriteAsync(
            new WriteData
            {
                DataPart = new WriteChunk
                {
                    Data = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, stream.Length),
                }
            },
            cancellationToken);
}
```

And on the other side:

```cs
var stream1 = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(requestStream.Current.DataPart.Data));
using var zipArchiveSubexport = new ZipArchive(stream1);
var t = zipArchiveSubexport.Entries.First();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's all about encoding. UTF8 doesn't fit for this purpose. I rewrite it on base64 string and it works